# Extract numbers from string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scanf

I'm working with sscanf to extract a number from a string. The strings are usually in the form of:

```
'44 ppm'
'10 gallons'
'23.4 inches'
```

but ocassionally they are in the form of:

```
'<1 ppm'
```

If I use the following code:

```
x = sscanf('1 ppm','%f')
```

I get an output of

```
1
```

But if I add the less than sign in front of the one:

```
x = sscanf('<1 ppm','%f')
```

I get:

```
[]
```

How can I write this code so this actually produces a number? I'm not sure yet what number it should print...but let's just say it should print **1** for the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html?refresh=true):

```
s= '<1 ppm';
x=regexp(s, '.*?(\d+(\.\d+)*)', 'tokens' )

x{1}
```

---

Demo :

```
>> s= {'44 ppm', '10 gallons', '23.4 inches', '<1 ppm' } ;
>> x = regexp(s, '.*?(\d+(\.\d+)*)', 'tokens' );
>> cellfun( @(x) disp(x{1}), x )  % Demo for all
    '44'

    '10'

    '23.4'

    '1'
```